# Have we ever observed a body, such as a large asteroid, "hitting" the Sun?

Tags: solar-system, the-sun, observational-astronomy, asteroids, comets

Some other SE questions about launching ICBM's into the sun got me wondering whether we have ever observed an object on a path that intersected with the Sun? How close did it get?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

and here's a video of "a Giant Comet Hitting the Sun":

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mat4dWpszoQ

[The impact occurred sometime during May 10-11, 2011.  The comet was not named but believed to be a member of the Kreutz family of comets](http://www.space.com/11663-comet-hits-sun-solar-explosion.html)

#### Many close calls

Before this spectacular plunge we had witnessed several other comets graze (come close without hitting) the Sun.

[I've included a nice picture of comet Lovejoy after its close approach of the Sun brought it through the Sun's corona around December 15, 2011](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sunearth/news/comet-lovejoy.html):

[image: Comet Lovejoy grazing the Sun]

#### What happens when a comet hits the sun?

It acts like [a supersonic snowball in Hell](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn27954-what-would-happen-if-a-massive-comet-crashed-into-the-sun/)

> If a comet is big enough and passes close enough, the steep fall into
>   the sun’s gravity would accelerate it to more than 600 kilometres per
>   second. At that speed, drag from the sun’s lower atmosphere would
>   flatten the comet into a pancake right before it exploded in an
>   airburst, releasing ultraviolet radiation and X-rays that we could see
>   with modern instruments.
>
> The crash would unleash as much energy as a magnetic flare or coronal
>   mass ejection, but over a much smaller area. “It’s like a bomb being
>   released in the sun’s atmosphere,” Brown says. The momentum propelled
>   by the comet could even make the sun ring like a bell with subsequent
>   sun-quakes echoing through the solar atmosphere.